# Two global IPv6 addresses?

Tags: ipv6

What is the scope of the second IPv6 address `fdee:de36:ce2c:0:174:d4b5:64b7:33f9` ? Netsh confirms that both are global/public. Is there any reason I get 2 global IPv6 addresses?

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Dell Wireless 1395 WLAN Mini-Card
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1F-E1-83-97-2A
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2a02:2f07:6171:ce00:174:d4b5:64b7:33f9(Preferred)
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fdee:de36:ce2c:0:174:d4b5:64b7:33f9(Preferred)
Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2a02:2f07:6171:ce00:78fc:b337:93ac:fb6b(Preferred)
Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : fdee:de36:ce2c:0:78fc:b337:93ac:fb6b(Preferred)
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::174:d4b5:64b7:33f9%3(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.122(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, April 12, 2015 12:29:05 AM
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Monday, April 13, 2015 3:20:04 PM
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::cab3:73ff:fe32:3dfa%3
                                    192.168.1.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

**Update:**
Ok, `fdee:de36:ce2c:0:174:d4b5:64b7:33f9` is definitely not a global IPv6 address, because it fails to connect to a remote address. But what is it? It's not a site-local either according to [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726952.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Use of site local IPv6 addresses was deprecated in 2004. It was deprecated because site local addresses suffer from addressing conflicts the same way RFC 1918 addresses do.

Comment: You should check if your router announces that Unique Local Address prefix in addition to the global prefix.

Comment: @Dubu Yes, it's advertised by the router along with the global prefix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `fdee:...` addresses are part of the [Unique Local Unicast](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193) allocation (`fc00::/7`).

> These    addresses are called Unique Local IPv6 Unicast Addresses and
> are    abbreviated in this document as Local IPv6 addresses.  They are
> not    expected to be routable on the global Internet.  They are
> routable    inside of a more limited area such as a site.  They may
> also be    routed between a limited set of sites.

See IANA's [Internet Protocol Version 6 Address Space](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-address-space/ipv6-address-space.xhtml) for an overview of existing allocations.